# I need help on manipulating this expression:

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Assume that $(4k + 3) ^ 2 - (4k + 3)$ is not divisible by 4. If this is true, prove that 
$(4(k+1) + 3) ^ 2 - (4(k+1) + 3)$ is not divisible by 4.

I need to prove this for my induction problem, and I've tried manipulating the second expression as much as I can but haven't arrived at a situation where I can use the first expression. Any help is appreciated, could anyone show me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510290/proof-by-induction-or-contradiction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=4k+3$. Then 
$$b=(4(k+1) + 3) ^ 2 - (4(k+1) + 3)=(a+4)^2-(a+4)=(a^2-a)+4(2a+3)$$
So, $b$ is a multiple of $4$ iff $a^2-a$ is a multiple of $4$, which it is not, by hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just have one question, could you explain how (a + 4)^2 - (a + 4) become (a^2 - a) + 8a, please?

Comment: My mistake. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally understand how to manipulate it this way.